# please help---Your device is corrupt. It cannot be trusted and will not boot LG g5

Tags: 7.0-nougat

Yesterday, my phone gave this error-Your device is corrupt. It cannot be trusted and will not boot LG g5 - and it does not open. Power button, volume up+ power button does not react to anything. what should i do?? how can i work my phone.

Comment: Did you install any new software or custom ROMs before this happened?